# Custom template page with custom archives listing by user

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, archives

I'm having an archive page for my post type. It's working, I'm using the template part with the `get_post_type()` parameters.

**content-activite.php:**

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail();
$attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
$attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment($attachment_id);
?>

<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-3 mb-4">
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $attachment_meta['src']; ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $attachment_meta['alt']; ?>">
            <div class="card-body flex-fill">
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <p class="m-0">
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to create the same layout with the same archive but for my current user. So I've created my page, assign a template to this and create my custom query.

But when I use this `($post_type = get_post_type())`:

```
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_post();
        get_template_part('template-parts/content', $post_type);
    endwhile;
endif;
```

`the_title();` is getting the name of the page, and not the name of my post. How can I get the name of my post?

**PS:**

I will need to change some data displayed on the template-part, but use one file only for the activities of my user and my archives.

Comment: remove that extra `the_post();` after `$the_query->the_post();`.

Comment: That's it ! don't know, why, didn't work the first time :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing that extra `the_post();` after `$the_query->the_post();`.

That will solve the problem. You may just use that once on the Query object. You have a custom quesry, then just call it on that exact object is required.